# PHP - How to run a script multiple times parallel

Tags: php

I want to run multiple instances of the following script parallel:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 1000; ) {
   echo "It works! Woohoo.<br/>";
   sleep(1);

   flush();
   ob_flush();
 }
```

I have included the httpd-mpm.conf in Apache's httd.conf, but it still doesn't work.
I'am using WAMP with Windows7. Is there a way to get this working?

Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure PHP is single-threaded.

Comment: call the script multiple times, i would suggest exec()

Comment: PHP is desperately single-threaded, there are so many things that would break if you brought in multithreading. You can use `exec` to spawn more processes, which will run asynchronously to your program, but that's about it AFAIK.

Comment: @Rocket Yes, it´s but everyone of us knows that that we can get multiple threads.

Comment: @zneak You could manually fork processes with the [Pcntl extension](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) (yuck), or you could call a script multiple times in parallel with `curl_multi_exec()` ([example here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9978964/185544)). No option is really clean or desirable. :-)

Comment: @Wiseguy, I actually meant that spawning more processes was the only way to have parallelism, not that `exec` was the only way to do it. But yeah. I guess we agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is single threaded, but there are some tricks to get multiple threads in order to offload heavy tasks to the background. One is to use Gearman, another is to use the new events introduced in PHP 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use PHP use CGI or Java Servlets.