# runing script in background and returning its pid from php

Tags: php, linux, shell

I try to invoke an app inside php:

```
ob_start();
passthru("(cd /opt/server/TrackServer/release && ./TrackServer& ) && pidof TrackServer");
$pid = ob_get_clean();
var_dump($pid);
exit;
```

The goal is to run TrackServer within its path and to get it's process id so I can close it after I do some test.

When I run the command in terminal:

```
(cd /opt/server/TrackServer/release && nohup ./TrackServer&) && pidof TrackServer
```

I get correct pid returned but in php the command stops and doesn't go further, the TrackServer is started and running but I have to kill it from terminal to unblock the php script, after killing the process the php script prints the correct pid for the process I've just closed from terminal.

1. Why the command stops?
2. Is there a way to make it run in php the way I'am trying to run it (without forking to a new thread)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT:
I found a working solution:

```
ob_start();
passthru("/bin/bash -c 'cd /opt/server/TrackServer/release && nohup ./TrackServer&' > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
passthru("pidof TrackServer");
$pid = ob_get_clean();
```

The command was stopping because:

[Run multiple exec commands at once (But wait for the last one to finish)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978964/run-multiple-exec-commands-at-once-but-wait-for-the-last-one-to-finish)

> PHP's exec function will always wait for a response from your
>   execution. However you can send the stdout & stderror of the process
>   to /dev/null (on unix) and have these all the scripts executed almost
>   instantly.

Answer (score 0):

From the [passthru manual page](https://www.php.net/passthru): The passthru() function is similar to the exec() function in that it executes a command.

What this means is that you can't execute your command line directly, as this runs several commands and relies on the shell to implement backgrounding and subshells as needed.

Try this instead:

```
passthru("/bin/bash -c 'cd /opt/server/TrackServer/release && nohup ./TrackServer& && pidof TrackServer'");
```

Comment: I did try passthru("/bin/bash -c 'cd /opt/server/TrackServer/release && nohup ./TrackServer&'"); but it stops at runtime